# C - undeclared (first use in this function) when it's actually declared

Tags: c

I simplified the code and still don't get why it says the struct isn't declared when it's declared right above

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
        struct s
        {
            char n[20];
            char p[20];
        };

        struct s X = malloc(sizeof(s));

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `s` is not declared.  `struct s` is the name of the type you defined. Also you cannot assign the result of `malloc` to a struct.  You could do `struct s X;`, or `struct s *pX = malloc( sizeof *pX );`

Comment: Note that C and C++ have different rules in this area. In C, `struct s { ... }` defines a type named `struct s`. In C++, the same definition creates a type called `s` (which can also be referred to as `struct s`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the you are defining the type `struct s` but not declaring the a variable or type named `s`.

For this reason, when you call `sizeof(s)` the symbol `s` is undeclared

As a side note, the variable `X` is defined as a `struct s` variable. If you're going to use `malloc` you probably want to assign the memory to a pointer (`struct s *X = ...`).

Consider:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    struct s
    {
        char n[20];
        char p[20];
    };

    struct s *X = malloc(sizeof(struct s)); /* <= note the struct keyword and pointer */

    return 0;
}
```

In addition, there is no need to name the `struct` type if you're not going to reference that type name. It's perfectly legal to use an anonymous struct:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    struct
    {
        char n[20];
        char p[20];
    } * x; /* <= note the variable name */

    x = malloc(sizeof(*x));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Either use a typedef like

```
    typedef struct s
    {
        char n[20];
        char p[20];
    } s;
```

and then

```
struct s *X = malloc(sizeof(s));
```

or

```
s *X = malloc(sizeof(s));
```

or even like

```
s *X = malloc(sizeof( *X));
```

Or without the typedef you have to use the keyword `struct`

```
struct s *X = malloc(sizeof(struct s));
```

or

```
struct s *X = malloc(sizeof( *X));
```